# jQuery ajax-call response is partly undefined while network answer (f+12) looks absolutely correct

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I use an oracle-db and a php-script which is called by an query ajax-call.

php-script:

```
$query = 'SELECT pl.event_id, pl.og2, d.name dst, pl.state, pl.note, pl.createdate FROM publevels pl
  LEFT JOIN dst d on (d.og2 = pl.og2)
  WHERE pl.event_id = ' . params::$data['id'];
$statement = oci_parse(database::$oracle, $query);
oci_execute($statement);
while ($row = oci_fetch_assoc($statement)) {
  $result[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($result);
```

The ajax-call:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: "index.php?module=ajax&view=read_publevels",
  data: {
    id: currentId
  },
  success: function(data) {                                           
    console.log(data);
  }
})
```

this works for nearly every dataset. but in some cases the console.log() results apartly undefined answer... i dont know why this only happens sometimes. the log looks like this:

```
[object Object],[object Object]    [
      0: {
         undefined: undefined
      },
      1: {
         [functions]: ,
         __proto__: { },
         CREATEDATE: "2019-05-23 08:30:16",
         DST: "PW Nürnberg-Rathaus",
         EVENT_ID: "41114",
         NOTE: "import",
         OG2: "0900514010500",
         STATE: "on"
      },
      length: 2    ]
```

the mysterious thing is, if i take a look in the network traffic with the browsers developer tools (f12) the traffic seems absolutely okay.

```
[{
"EVENT_ID":"41114",
"OG2":"0900500000000",
"DST":"PP Mittelfranken",
"STATE":"on",
"NOTE":"import",
"CREATEDATE":"2019-05-23 08:23:40"},
{"EVENT_ID":"41114",
"OG2":"0900514010500",
"DST":"PW N\u00fcrnberg-Rathaus",
"STATE":"on",
"NOTE":"import",
"CREATEDATE":"2019-05-23 08:30:16"
}]
```

So i dont know why sometimes the first dataset is not correctly delivered?! Any ideas?

Comment: Do you modify `data` after receiving it? The console log is a live copy of the object, so if you modify it before expanding the log, you'll see the updated version.

Comment: Change it to `console.log(JSON.stringify(data))` to log a snapshot.

Comment: and make sure it's the first line of your `success:` callback

Comment: JSON.stringify gives the correct answer: 

[{"EVENT_ID":"41202","OG2":"0900500000000","DST":"PP Mittelfranken","STATE":"on","NOTE":"import","CREATEDATE":"2019-05-23 08:26:54"},{"EVENT_ID":"41202","OG2":"0900514010500","DST":"PW Nürnberg-Rathaus","STATE":"on","NOTE":"import","CREATEDATE":"2019-05-23 08:26:54"}]

i tryed to make a JSON.parse with this string but after this the first dataset ist undefined again... 

I didnt do any modifications before the log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the mistake. I used the data array very later in a function which moved some entrys from the end to the beginning in depency to other data. In this case the other data had'nt the entry "**PW Nürnberg-Rathaus**" so the data was set to "undefined".

And because of the superduper chaining of variables the data is undefined before the faulty function did the undefining job. I found it out after i built a "handmade" JSON.parse which worked perfectly. After i linked the result again to the faulty function it was undefined like the first data.

So thank you guys for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Does it always enter success? If not you can add error block to check if there is an error on the server side.

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: "index.php?module=ajax&view=read_publevels",
  data: {
    id: currentId
  },
  success: function(data) {                                           
    console.log(data);
  },error(data)
{
console.log(data);
}
})
```

Comment: it always enter the success. otherwise i wouldnt see the log because it only appears on entering the success block. to check this i addad a error-block with the result that it isnt entered ;)